# ERROR: failed to validate image tag(s): could not parse reference: docker.io/library/projectName:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I was getting `ERROR: failed to validate image tag(s): could not parse reference: docker.io/library/projectName:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` while building the docker image.

I am using "spotify" maven dependency in the SpringBoot project.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <repository>${project.artifactId}</repository>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After running a few Google queries, it seems I am the only one getting this issue.

The confluence URL in below stack trace just says it's "uncatched runtime exceptions".

**Stack trace:**

```
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to validate image tag(s): could not parse reference: docker.io/library/projectName:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  33.479 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-02T05:33:13+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image (default-cli) on project projectName: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 3 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image (default-cli) on project projectName: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 3
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 3
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.BuilderException: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 3
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Lifecycle.run (Lifecycle.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Lifecycle.execute (Lifecycle.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.executeLifecycle (Builder.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.build (Builder.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.buildImage (BuildImageMojo.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.execute (BuildImageMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue explanation:

The issue is with the name of the project. When docker says "could not parse reference" then it means the name of the docker file. Also, it "failed to validate image tag(s)" because initially, it was not able to parse the image.

Solution:

For some reason or probably it's by design, docker can not parse the image name if there are characters in Capital letter.

I just had to change the `artifactId` in my maven.xml file
`<artifactId>projectName</artifactId>` to `<artifactId>projectname</artifactId>`

Comment: Nice - this solved my issue!