# Google cloud build extract data from maven and use them in multiple steps

Tags: maven, google-cloud-build

My cloud build needs to do the following

- build maven
- build docker images using the maven plugin
- Retag the docker images with naming appropriate for pushing to GC artifact registry
- push those images to the artifact registry

I want to use the pom version as a suffix in the naming. During the mvn goal I can extract the mvn version, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line).
The suggestion of GC [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps) is to write variables in files and then read them. However, that does not work in this case. When I push the artifacts

```
images: [europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-artifact-repo/my-image-name:$(cat /workspace/pom_version.txt)]
```

This fails because the file is not found. Is this possible to work around somehow?
Code:

```
steps:
  - name: 'maven:3.9.1'
    id: Extract project version from pom
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >
        mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout > /workspace/version.txt
    entrypoint: bash
  - name: 'maven:3.9.1'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >
        mvn -version

        mvn clean install -DskipTests

        mvn -B -f ./my-module/pom.xml org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:build-image -DskipTests
    id: Build all applications and create docker images
    entrypoint: bash
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    id: Retag my module image
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - - '-c'
      - >
        docker tag my-module:$(cat /workspace/version.txt) europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/my-repo/my-module:$(cat /workspace/version.txt)
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - image
      - list
images:
  - >-
    europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/my-repo/my-module:$(cat /workspace/version.txt)
```

Error on trigger

```
Failed to trigger build: invalid build: invalid image name "europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/my-module:$(cat /workspace/version.txt)": could not parse reference: europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/my-module:$(cat /workspace/version.txt)
```

Latest logs requested

```
starting build "21bf9cc4-a3b2-4fa5-9f4a-227251418f69"

FETCHSOURCE
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://github.com/*****************************************
 * branch            c67f9196c83cb979375e56c20fdf1b74c000b6fb -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at c67f919 up the pom
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom"
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": Pulling image: maven:3.9.1
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": 3.9.1: Pulling from library/maven
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": 1bc677758ad7: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": 0d0e0ecb256a: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": f2771a8876bc: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": b345cc3cb9aa: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": cbe2c70538c6: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": 2dfc9d99b05b: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": cfed619e8a87: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": 26665a7643b2: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": e5e3e15e6256: Already exists
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": Digest: sha256:2dee414ad9997352b313031ce3ef2c10b119a333fba743f456ec4b1915081173
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": Status: Downloaded newer image for maven:3.9.1
Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom": docker.io/library/maven:3.9.1
Finished Step #0 - "Extract project version from pom"
Starting Step #1 - "Build all applications and create docker images"
Step #1 - "Build all applications and create docker images": Already have image (with digest): maven:3.9.1
Step #1 - "Build all applications and create docker images": 0.0.0.0
Finished Step #1 - "Build all applications and create docker images"
PUSH
DONE
```

Comment: Can you share the details from `build logs`? Can you confirm whether it is working locally? Also can you share your `yaml` file?

Comment: @RoopaM added the file, I do not have the logs handy, because i have not run it in a while, but the issue was that the file to which I right the version was not accessible in the images section.

Comment: I recreated on my side. I got error saying: `could not parse reference` hoping you got the same error. can you check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62143325/18265570)? that might be the issue.

Comment: @RoopaM added the trigger error

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your issue on my console and I got the exact error as yours. I believe the issue is with using `$(cat /workspace/pom\_version.txt)` in the `images` step. As mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#images:%7E:text=npmPackage) `images` tag accepts only `strings`.  It seems it does not support evaluating bash commands.

Hence try to store the maven version under the variable and use it as a tag for a `image`.

```
_MVN_VERSION=$(help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
```

And also it seems you have used entry points after `args`. It is not recommended to use `entrypoint` after the args. See [example doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps#passing_data_using_workspaces) for correct syntax.

### Update

As I mentioned in the comment, for executing the "cat" command a `bash shell` is needed and you were trying to run that from the image section which is not aware of it. And regarding variables. `Cloud build` doesn't support reading values from file to variable and surpasses it to other steps.

And the workaround I can think of is to try to extract the version in the local shell script env variable and pass the value using `gcloud build submit --substitution`. But as you mentioned, this workaround is prone to error. Hence, I suggest you raise a request in [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Can i overwrite substiution variables?

Comment: Also the reason that I use entrypoint is to be able to use cat, I cannot cat if my entrypoint is docker

Comment: This does not work, i run the following


`steps:
  - name: 'maven:3.9.1'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >
        _MVN_VERSION=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q
        -DforceStdout)
    id: Extract project version from pom
    entrypoint: bash
  - name: 'maven:3.9.1'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        echo $_MVN_VERSION
    id: Build all applications and create docker images
    entrypoint: bash`



The echo in the 2nd step is whatever I provide as input in the substitute variable

Comment: Sorry for the terrible format, posting code in comments is not ideal

Comment: Can you share the build logs that you are getting now?

Comment: I added them, i provided as input for the version 0.0.0.0 which is not my mvn version. I used the cat before because that is the suggested way by google to pass information between steps https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps

Comment: @Dimitris, 

I apologize for miscommunication. for executing the "cat" command a `bash shell` is needed and you were trying to run that from the image section which is not aware of it. And regarding variables. `Cloud build` doesn't support reading value from file to variable and surpass it to other steps. And the workaround i can think is to try to extract version in local shell script env variable and pass the value using `gcloud build submit -substitution`.

Comment: Yes, indeed i have already implemented that work around. However it is redundant information and prone to errors. The images are built with the maven plugin so they need to be retagged. If the version of the user does not match the one from the pom will lead to an error. I was hopping that I could pass that information somehow to the images.

Comment: @Dimitris As I mentioned in the answer feel free to raise a request for gcp.